Setup application only once for all test files
I have a Jest setup where I need to test an application. This application takes about five seconds to spin up, which is longer than the tests themselves take in most test files (there are a lot of test files each with only a couple of tests).
This slows the tests down by quite a sizable degree. I do not think there is a lot of potential to optimize the application's startup time and my preferred option would be to start it once and then re-use the same initialized application across all test files.
I am aware of the globalSetup / globalTeardown scripts, but since each test file is run with a different module registry, the attempt to import the application there and call its initialize() function was not fruitful, because as soon as I import the application in a test file, it is a completely different object.
Also, while the application has a webserver, it is not sufficient to start it in a subprocess and then only communicate via HTTP with it. We are unit-testing, so we want to access specific functions inside of the application.
Is there a way to access the same application instance across all test files?
